# Calling Custom Post Meta

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

http://www.vooshthemes.com/blog/wordpress-tip/create-a-professional-portfolio-using-wordpress-3-0-custom-post-types/

I'm using the above tutorial to build custom portfolio pages.  The custom portfolio pages are working... but I can't figure out how to display the Website URL I enter in my custom post meta field (website_url).

Shouldn't `<?php echo $website_url; ?>` work?

How do I call specific post meta?  The normal call for all post_meta is `<?php the_meta(); ?>`, but what if I just want to call a specific piece of it (website_url in this example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `<?=$website_url?>` in the portfolio template like

```
<strong>URL: </strong><a href="<?=$website_url?>"><?=$website_url?></a>
```

to make it like follow

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Portfolio
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="content">
    <?php 
        $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 10)); 
    ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <?php   
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $screenshot_url = $custom["screenshot_url"][0];
        $website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];
    ?>
        <div id="portfolio-item">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <a href="<?=$website_url?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </a>
        <strong>URL: </strong><a href="<?=$website_url?>"><?=$website_url?></a>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>  
        </div><!-- #content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

You can change the placement to match your standers

Comment: did you find it use full if so please mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are inside the loop:

```
$website_url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'website_url', true );
```

Where `$post->ID` is the id of the current post. Either accessed by the `$post` global or `the_ID()` / `get_the_ID()` or some other method.